# How to change will_paginate URLs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, will-paginate

I'm trying to change the `will_paginate` links  from the format of `/list?page=1` to `/list/page/1`.  I have the routes setup right for this, but `will_paginate` is using the query string in links rather than my pretty URL style.  How to tell it otherwise?

I'm using will_paginate **2.3.16** and Rails **2.3.14**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

will_paginate uses the `url_for` helper. If you define routes containing the parameters it uses, it should generate pretty urls.

```
map.connect '/lists/page/:page', :controller => 'lists', :action => 'index'
```

Please make sure, you define this route *above* any routes that could also match your controller action. Even better: exclude the index action like this:

```
map.resources :lists, :except => [:index]
```

Comment: Thanks.  I just had my routes screwed up!  Thanks for your answer and here's a bounty

Comment: Now `map.connect` called `match '/list/page/:page' => 'lists#index'`. Anw, there is a typo on your `map.connnect` @iblue, just saying because this post was useful for me :D Please correct me if I'm wrong, rails newbie

Answer (score 2):

You have several options here:

1st option: monkey patch `WillPaginate::ActionView::LinkRenderer#url`, which currently has the following url logic:

```
def url(page)
  @base_url_params ||= begin
    url_params = merge_get_params(default_url_params)
    merge_optional_params(url_params)
  end

  url_params = @base_url_params.dup
  add_current_page_param(url_params, page)

  @template.url_for(url_params)
end
```

So, I imagine that you can do something like `"/list/page/#{page}"` instead.

The other way is to fully implement the renderer (by subclassing `WillPaginate::ViewHelpers::LinkRenderer`), and then providing it as `:renderer => MyRendererClass` when calling will_paginate.