# After ajax request will_pagenate doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, will-paginate, kaminari

I'm using ajax request to update my `lists`.
And the `lists` are shown with `will_paginate`.

Before ajax post it works all fine.

The original pagination url is like `/users/username?page=2`.

After posting to url `users/update_lists_from_twitter` for refresh the page, the pagination url become like `/users/update_lists_from_twitter?page=2`.

It seems `will_paginate` refers post request url.

How can I fix it? I've read through `will_paginate` and `kaminari` documents, but I couldn't find anything.

Here is my controller,

```
# users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html
  def show
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @list_users = @user.list_users.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
  end
  def update_lists_from_twitter
    current_user.update_lists_from_twitter
    @list_users = current_user.list_users.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
    respond_with(current_user, layout: false)
  end
end
```

and view,

```
# users/show.html.erb
<div id='user-lists'>
  <%= will_paginate @list_users, controller: 'users', action: 'index', renderer: FoundationPagination::Rails %>
  <% @list_users.each do |list_user|  %>
    <%= render "shared/member", member: list_user %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and coffee script.

```
# users.js.coffee
$ ->
  $('#reload-list').on(
    'ajax:success': (data, res, xhr) ->
      $("#user-lists").html res
    )
```

Comment: First of all, we're going to need your view code and controller code. However, the usual page variable being passed in is `page` not `pages`. Are you sure that's not the problem?

Comment: `pages` was my typo. And I added my code. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Can you show some code of yours? I meet this case on my own. Yes that behavior was natural coming from `will_paginate`.

I once trying to solve with manually set the URL like

```
<%= will_paginate @models, :controller => 'models', :action => 'index' %>
```

You can check on [How to change will_paginate URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022759/how-to-change-will-paginate-urls)

Please correct me if I'm wrong.